# Git cannot ignore node_modules in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, npm, gitignore

Here is the scenario, my colleague has already pushed the node_modules folder from his machine to remote repo.

On my machine, I ran the "npm_install" to install all required dependencies. Now, when Iam trying to sync with remote repo to fetch new changes. I get this message:

```
 Cannot pull because there are uncommitted changes.
 Commit or undo your changes before pulling again. See the Output window for details.
```

In Changes tab : my node_modules directory is included. So, I need to ignore it.

I tried the following:

1. added to tsconfig.ts :  **"exclude": ["node_modules"]**
2. added the "node_modules" to gitignore

[image]

**Note:** The node_modules directory is in *Repo\Comaps\Compas_ng\Compas_ng* folder which is a web application in a solution. The gitignore file is in *Repo\Compas* directory which is the parent.

[image]

But, when sync it again, the node_modules still appearing in the changes tab.

What should I do to resolve the problem? and why the options didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clean cache of node_modules folder:

```
git rm --cached -r node_modules
```